# What does this types of "if" mean?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

I've been reading some ebooks about cocoa, so I can learn more, but I don't have so clearly what this types of "if" mean:

```
if(!something)
if(something)
```

And I suppose that:

```
if (something !=nil)
```

Means that if something doesn't exists, right?

Thanks :)

Comment: It most programming languages there is a boolean data type: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_data_type

Answer (score 8):

In C everything un-equal `NULL` or `0` is considered `true`.

Thus

```
if (!something)
```

is identical to

```
if (!(something != nil))
```

and thus identical to

```
if (something == nil)
```

in case of Objective-C objects (as `nil` is basically `NULL`).

So `if (something)` is basically a short-hand for `if (something != nil)`.
And `if (!something)` is basically a short-hand for `if (something == nil)`.

For non Objective-C pointers you could just replace `nil` with `NULL`. (`nil` is more or less only syntax sugar anyway.)

You can also use this to check if an integer is un-equal `0`:
As such the condition `if ([myArray count])` is `true` unless `myArray` is empty.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that something is a pointer to an NSObject.

```
if(something)
```

This returns YES if something is a non-nil pointer

```
if(!something)
```

This returns YES if something is nil. This in this case because `something` is nil, and `!` (the not operator) inverts this to become true,

`if(something)` is the same as `if(something != nil)`. But most programmers I know think this is a tautology and prefer the shorter expression.

While I'm at it - you may see this written as `if(nil != something)`. The reason for this is that if, by accident you write `=` instead of `!=` this will raise an error as you can't set a value to nil, but if it was the other way around and you mis-wrote the condition, it would set the value of something to nil, which may not be what you want to do.

Comment: Thanks too! :D both have been so useful!

Comment: Thankfully **clang** warns you about the latter, these days. :)

Answer (score 0):

This is general syntax for most C-based languages. What you need to realize is that the if statement checks the expression in the parantheses to be false(zero) or true(1 or non-zero). So, when you say "if(something)", you're basically asking if to check if it's: 1. true or false(for Boolean expressions); 2. Zero or non-zero (for arithmetic expressions); 3. Null or valid address (for pointers, strings, etc).

Now you need to remember that the "!" operator is used to negate an expression i.e. Bitwise change every "0" bit in the result to a "1" and vice versa. So, basically you're checking if the negative of the result is true or non-zero.

In short, you use "if(something)" when you want the code snippet to execute when "something" is true or non-zero. You use "if(!something)" when you want your code snippet to execute when "something" is false or zero.